# InvalidOwnerException Whilte to create Row Of Master/Detial ViewObject Programaticlly in ADF

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have 2 viewObjects, Strategy and Objective, and there is a master/detail relation between the two tables. i've aslo created association between the two view object .

```
Strategy has primary key strgID, and strgName
```

and the Objective table has

```
objvID as primary key, strgID as foreign key, and objvName
```

I am getting the data as JSON object, where there is one strategy, and many objectives below it. What I need to do is insert a record in the strategy table, take the ID which is auto-generated by DBsequence, and use this ID as a foreign key when inserting into the objectives table.

I'm trying to Do all this programmatically with ViewObjectImpl Class and this is my Code :

```
 AppModuleImpl am = null;

    try {

        am = (AppModuleImpl) Configuration.createRootApplicationModule(AM_DEF_NAME, AM_CONFIG_NAME);


         BpmStrgViewImpl strgView = am.getBpmStrgView1(); // this the master viewobject
        BpmObjvViewImpl objvView = am.getBpmObjvView1(); // this is the detail viewobject
```

// i've traversed the JSON and get the value needed to insert a row in the master view object

```
Row row = strgView.createRow();

        // the StrategyID is DB Sequence

        row.setAttribute("StrgNameAr", json.get("name"));

        strgView.insertRow(row);
```

now the masterViewObject Has 1 row 
now i will insert the detail viewObject Rows and this is the code
      // while the json has objective rows i will do the following :

```
         Row row = objvView.createRow(); // The Exceptions Happens at this line exactly 


        // object id is DB Sequence 
        row.setAttribute("strgID" , " the new generated sequence value from the master row " ) ;
        row.setAttribute("objvName", "Value");
        objvView.insertRow(row);
         am.getTransaction().commit();
```

a

```
nd this is the Exception : 

oracle.jbo.InvalidOwnerException: JBO-25030: Detail entity BpmObjv with row key oracle.jbo.Key[-2 ] cannot find or invalidate its owning entity.

                at oracle.jbo.server.EntityImpl.internalCreate(EntityImpl.java:1585)

                at oracle.jbo.server.EntityImpl.create(EntityImpl.java:977)

                at oracle.jbo.server.EntityImpl.callCreate(EntityImpl.java:1412)

                at oracle.jbo.server.ViewRowStorage.create(ViewRowStorage.java:1076)

                at oracle.jbo.server.ViewRowImpl.create(ViewRowImpl.java:572)

                at oracle.jbo.server.ViewRowImpl.callCreate(ViewRowImpl.java:610)

                at oracle.jbo.server.ViewObjectImpl.createInstance(ViewObjectImpl.java:6343)

                at oracle.jbo.server.QueryCollection.createRowWithEntities(QueryCollection.java:2202)

                at oracle.jbo.server.ViewRowSetImpl.createRowWithEntities(ViewRowSetImpl.java:2830)

                at oracle.jbo.server.ViewRowSetImpl.doCreateAndInitRow(ViewRowSetImpl.java:2876)

                at oracle.jbo.server.EntityRowSetImpl.doCreateAndInitRow(EntityRowSetImpl.java:159)

                at oracle.jbo.server.ViewRowSetImpl.createRow(ViewRowSetImpl.java:2852)

                at model.BpmStrgImpl.create(BpmStrgImpl.java:390)

                at oracle.jbo.server.EntityImpl.callCreate(EntityImpl.java:1412)

                at oracle.jbo.server.ViewRowStorage.create(ViewRowStorage.java:1076)

                at oracle.jbo.server.ViewRowImpl.create(ViewRowImpl.java:572)

                at oracle.jbo.server.ViewRowImpl.callCreate(ViewRowImpl.java:610)

                at oracle.jbo.server.ViewObjectImpl.createInstance(ViewObjectImpl.java:6343)

                at oracle.jbo.server.QueryCollection.createRowWithEntities(QueryCollection.java:2202)

                at oracle.jbo.server.ViewRowSetImpl.createRowWithEntities(ViewRowSetImpl.java:2830)

                at oracle.jbo.server.ViewRowSetImpl.doCreateAndInitRow(ViewRowSetImpl.java:2876)

                at oracle.jbo.server.ViewRowSetImpl.createRow(ViewRowSetImpl.java:2852)

                at oracle.jbo.server.ViewObjectImpl.createRow(ViewObjectImpl.java:12867)

                at model.MyClass.traverseTree(MyClass.java:23)

                at model.MyClass.main(MyClass.java:71)
```

Comment: next time try googling the error.https://community.oracle.com/thread/2531020

Answer (score 0):

i've solved it by following :

```
am.getStrgObjvViewLink().setSource(strgView);
am.getStrgObjvViewLink().setDestination(objvView);
```